# Isolating scopes in Angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive that has to dinamically add some divs to the template. The thing is that everytime i add a new one the ones created before that one get replaced with the new content. I know this has to do with isolating the directive's scope but it doesn't seem to work. I've tried `scope: {}` and `scope: true` with the same result.

Directive:

```
angular.module('bucket.directives', [])     
.directive('bucketList', ['$compile', function($compile) {

  var viaUrlTemplate = '<span class="bucketItem viaUrl">{{ displayName }} <i class="icon-delete">x</i></span>';

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      scope.$on('urlBucketAdded', function(event, bucketInfo) {
        scope.displayName = bucketInfo.bucketName;

        scope.$apply(function() {
          var content = $compile(viaUrlTemplate)(scope);
          element.append(content);
        });
      });

    }
  }
}]);
```

The HTML looks something like this:

```
<div bucket-list class="bucketList">

  // new elements in 'viaUrlTemplate' get inserted here

</div>
```

So when I try to add new elements with displayName -> Content 1, Content 2 and Content 3 I get:

```
<div bucket-list class="bucketList">

 <span class="bucketItem viaUrl"> Content 3 <i class="icon-delete">x</i></span>
 <span class="bucketItem viaUrl"> Content 3 <i class="icon-delete">x</i></span>
 <span class="bucketItem viaUrl"> Content 3 <i class="icon-delete">x</i></span>

</div>
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Why not use an `ng-repeat` instead?  What you are trying to display doesn't have anything complex that requires a custom directive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could just use a regular variable to contain the displayName rather than using a scope variable (see this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y3X0mUeg5IVc4OF5ofRR?p=preview)):

```
scope.$on('urlBucketAdded', function(event, bucketInfo) {
        var displayName = bucketInfo.bucketName;
        var viaUrlTemplate = '<span class="bucketItem viaUrl">' + displayName + '<i class="icon-delete">x</i></span>';

       // scope.$apply(function() {
          var content = $compile(viaUrlTemplate)(scope);
          element.append(content);
      //  });
      });
```

the `scope` variable will stay the same in the directive no matter how many template divs you `compile` and add to it. This is exactly why you are seeing the new `displayName` overwrites the previous values, because you are just updating the scope variable `displayName` in that case.

Comment: thank you very much! i didn't know i could pass html directly from my directive. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, you don't need to use the $scope on the $compile service.

```
var content = $compile(viaUrlTemplate)({ displayName: bucketInfo.bucketName });
```

just using a custom object should solve your issue.